# Calculating Posterior Expected Utilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need help figuring out how to calculate the posterior expected utility.

```
E(U(D = 1,X | Y = 1))
```

I have the following information/probabilities.  There is more information available, but I believe the information listed should be sufficient.  If its not please let me know what else I need.

```
P(X) = 0.2
P(Y=1) = 0.4
P(X | Y=1) = 0.1
P(Y = 1 | x) = 0.2
P(Y = 1 | ~x) = 0.6
U(D = 1, x) = 400
U(D = 1, ~x) = 2
U(D = 2, x) = 20
U(D = 2, ~x) = 100
```

I may have found the solution.  I'm pretty sure it's just.

```
P(Y=1) * U(D=1, X) = 0.4 * 400
```

If that's wrong someone please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.   You want the expectation; the sum over the support of the product of the random variable and the conditional probability over the measure.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\,U(D=1, X \mid Y=1)\,)
& =\mathsf E(\,U(D=1, X) \mid Y=1)
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{k\in\{x, \neg x\}} U(D=1, k) \;\mathsf P(k\mid Y=1)
\\[1ex] & = U(D=1, x) \;\mathsf P(x\mid Y=1)+U(D=1, \neg x) \;\mathsf P(\neg x\mid Y=1)
\\[1ex] & = 400\cdot 0.1 + 2\cdot 0.9
\\[1ex] & = 41.8
\end{align}$$

Comment: The original question has everything within the utility function, like E(U(D=1, X | Y = 1)).  Do you think thats a typo and it should be how you put it (which is E(U(D=1, X) | Y = 1))?

Comment: I would say they are equivalent.